# What's the difference between "commit" and "commit work"?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I was asking in terms of the Oracle SQL*PLUS ...

Answer (score 17):

Nothing :-)

[Oracle says](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4010.htm)

> The WORK keyword is supported for
>   compliance with standard SQL. The
>   statements COMMIT and COMMIT WORK are
>   equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

Nothing - it's an optional statement

[See here for more details](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/transactions/commit.php)

[Quoting from this article](http://www.oracle-dba-online.com/sql/commit_rollback_savepoint.htm):

> To make the changes done in a
>   transaction permanent issue the COMMIT
>   statement.
>
> The syntax of COMMIT Statement is
>
> COMMIT  [WORK]  [COMMENT ‘your
>   comment’];
>
> WORK is optional.
>
> COMMENT is also optional, specify this
>   if you want to identify this
>   transaction in data dictionary
>   DBA_2PC_PENDING.

Answer (score 2):

Five characters - ' WORK'.

:-)

However, the effect of both commands is identical.

Share and enjoy.